# Slide html content

Tags: jquery

I found an example on how to use jquery slide effect, but im trying to modify it, so its not sliding all the divs, but only the once with a class of some name, I call the class: slide.

It works the first time, but then the child div is being replaced by a blank page, until the next class div will show.. How do I correct this in jquery?

I changed next("div") to next("div.slide") and I thought it was the only thing needed..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        .yourContainer{ position:relative; }
        .yourContainer div{ position:absolute; hight:300px; width:300px; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jq/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jq/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="yourContainer">
        <div class="slide" style="background:red;">some html
             <div style="background:pink;">noooo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" style="background:yellow;">Other HTML</div>
        <div class="slide" style="background:blue;">4 HTML</div>
        <div class="slide" style="background:green;">5 HTML</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function(){
    $('.yourContainer div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.yourContainer :first-child').fadeOut(1000).next("div.slide").fadeIn(400).end().appendTo('.yourContainer');}, 3000);
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it should show the content, so the pink, noooo, should be shown when the red is shown..

Comment: JSFiddle for those who want to try - http://jsfiddle.net/uzyJ7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start both animations at the same time so effect would seem better.
Here is a better version of what you want to achieve.

Here a demo: [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ds4EA/)

```
function nextSlide() {
    var container = $('.yourContainer'),
    // Your current slide jQuery element
        current_slide = container.children().first(),
    // Next sibling (slide) of current slide
        next_slide = current_slide.next();

    current_slide.fadeOut(1000);
    next_slide.fadeIn(1000, function () {
        // Append current_slide to the end of container
        // so it can move to the slide when interval has been fired again.
        current_slide.appendTo(container);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Start slider
    $('.yourContainer').children().hide().first().show();
    // Intervally move to the next slide
    setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the try! With nextSlide function, what happens is that it shows the green on every slide while quickly showing the other colors on the first run. After the first run, everything works as expected! So why could it be that it is not working as expected the first run though? :)

Comment: Checkout the demo its fixed now. The problem was that you should have initially hide all the sildes `.children().hide()` and only show the first slide `.first().show()`.

Comment: Excellent! If I can then ask another question about the same solution, how would I then stop/start the sliding? Maybe also a back/forward button? Would it be possible or would I have to find a jquery plugin for that, because it would be too detailed?

Comment: If you need a full-featured slider I suggest you to use a plugin instead of building one from the scratch (unless you want to challenge yourself and learn something). I've used `Nivo Slider` and it never let me down.

Comment: Hi! I decided to code it myself, and got the stop/start button to work, as the next slide button to work, but I have difficulties with the previous. Taken your code, I just changed current_slide.next(); to current_slide.prev(); and it doesnt show anything.. Do you have an idea of why this is mate?